# How to import python file located in same subdirectory in a pycharm project

Tags: python, pycharm, importerror

I have an input error in pycharm when debugging and running.

My project structure is rooted properly, `etc./HW3/.` so that `HW3` is the root directory.

I have a subfolder in HW3, `util`, and a file, `util/util.py`.  I have another file in `util` called `run_tests.py`.

In `run_tests.py`, I have the following import structure,

```
from util.util import my_functions, etc.
```

This yields an input error, `from util.util import load_dataset,proportionate_sample
ImportError: No module named 'util.util'; 'util' is not a package`

---

However, in the exact same project, in another directory (same level as `util`) called `data`, I have a file `data/data_prep.py`, which also imports functions from `util/util.py` using a similar import statement...and it runs without any problems.

---

Obviously, I am doing this in the course of doing a homework, so please understand: this is ancillary to the scope of the homework.

---

The problem goes away when I move the file to another directory.  So I guess this question is **How do I import a python file located in the same directory in a pycharm project?**  Because pycharm raises an error if I just do `import util` and prompts me to use the full name from the root.

Comment: do you have an `__init__.py` if no, create one and add from `util.util import my_function` then try importing it in the file

Comment: And I place `__init__.py` in the base directory (HW3 in my question) with that line in it?

Comment: no in the `util` folder, that tells python that it is a package, the `__init__.py` can also be used to import/load modules too

Comment: Ok, great, should I delete or do you want to answer?  And thanks, that is really useful info.  Been a crash course in python so far.

Comment: it'd be great to get some reps :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you don't have an `__init__.py` create one and add this line

```
from util.util import my_function
```

then you can easily import the module in your scripts
the `__init__.py` tells python that it should treat that folder as a python package, it can also be used to import/load modules too.

in most cases the `__init__.py` is empty.

Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#tut-packages):

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the
> directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
> directories with a common name, such as `string`, from unintentionally
> hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In
> the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can
> also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__`
> variable, described later.

Answer (score 112):

**Recommended Way:**

Make sure to set the working folder as `Sources`.

You can do it in `Pycharm` `->` `Preferences` `->` `Project: XYZ` `->` `Project Structure`

Select your working folder and mark it as `Sources`. Then Pycharm recognize the working folder as a Source folder for the project and you will be able to simply add other files within that folder by using

```
import filename.py
```

or

```
from filename.py import mudule1
```

=================

**Not recommended way:**

In `Pycharm`you can simply add `.` before the `.py` file which you are going to import it from the **same folder**. In your case it will be

```
from .util import my_functions
```

**Resource**

There is a good reference also for more information with example how to implement **Package Relative Imports**. I would highly recommend to check this page.

[Package Relative Imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports)

Comment: this solved my problem! my folder source was not set up correctly

Comment: This solved my problem too. I could run my code but before I marked it as `sources` PyCharm was complaining about "No module found..."

Comment: Ah, blessed relief!

Comment: this is good until you try to run the program from the terminal. At that moment all the ModuleNotFoundErrors appear.

Answer (score 23):

Right-click on the folder which you want to be marked as the source > Mark Directory as > Source root.

Comment: work likes a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it worked only when I omit the extension. Example:

```
import filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: May be a bit unrelated.

I was facing the same issue but I was unable to import a module in the same directory (rather than subdirectory as asked by OP) when running a **jupyter notebook** (here the directory didn't have __init__.py). Strangely, I had setup python path and interpreter location and everything. None of the other answers helped but changing the directory in python did.

```
import os
os.chdir(/path/to/your/directory/)
```

I'm using `PyCharm 2017.3` on `Ubuntu 16.04`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with pycharm, but the actual mistake was that the file I was trying to import didn't have a .py extension, even though I was able to run it as a standalone script. Look in the explorer window and make sure it has a .py extension. If not, right click on the file in the explorer window, pick refactor, and then rename it with a .py extension.

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm go to "Run - Configuration" and uncheck 
'Add Content root to Pythonpath' and 
'Add source roots to Pythonpath', 
then use

```
from filename import functionname
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was, the source directory was marked correctly, but my file to import was named starting with numeric value. Resolved by renaming it.

```
import 01_MyModuleToImport
```

to

```
import MyModuleToImport
```