# ImportError on Python

Tags: python, import, module, package

I'm new to python and I'm having this problem that I can't figure it out.

My file structure is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tHX0.png)

On Criador.py I have several functions, for example:

```
def doSomething():
pass
def doSomethingElse():
pass
```

and Im trying to use one of this functions on the Controller.py file:

The first thing I did was, on the Controller.py:

```
import Controller.Criador
```

and then tried to use that function as:

```
Controller.Criador.doSomething()
```

After running Controller.py, I got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Controller.Criador'; 'Controller' is not a package
```

I tried several other things, like:

```
from . import Criador
```

or

```
from Controller.Criador import doSomething
```

or

```
from Controller import Criador
```

and nothing helped, just changed the errors to:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Criador'
```

and

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Controller.Criador'; 'Controller' is not a package
```

and

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Criador'
```

Can someone give me a light about this? I'm using PyCharm and it does not give me any error when I declare the imports, only when I run the file

Comment: I think you need a __init__.py inside your Controller Folder

Comment: from what I researched, the __init__.py is no longer necessary in python 3.

Comment: You have the folder name and file name same which is creating problems. And if you are importing from a module in same directory `__init__.py` is not required, but if you importing like this `from Directory.Module import method` then the `Directory` must have a `__init__.py` to be considered as a package. Every time you got the `'Controller' is not a package` error was because there is not `__init__.py`

Comment: I was able to fix my problem with Edgar's answer! But thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

If **Controller.py** and **Criador.py** are in the same folder, you can do this inside **Controller.py**:

```
import Criador

Criador.doSomething()
```

Comment: when I try import Criador, PyCharm marks with a red underline in Criador, saying "No module named Criador". BUT, if I run the program, I get no error... Is PyCharm crazy?

Comment: More or less, but there are workarounds. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45395187/5535114).

Comment: Did that to my main folder (it turned to a blue folder) and it did not fixed it, but after that I did to all the folders in the project and the error is gone! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!